# Did Merkle invent cryptographic hashing?

Tags: hash, history

Chapter II of [Merkle's 1979 PhD thesis](http://www.merkle.com/papers/Thesis1979.pdf) is titled "One Way Hash Functions." The chapter appears to be the first reference to cryptographic hashing. The chapter has no references. Is there an earlier reference that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first paragraph of [this document](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3ana6sx75owoMJ%3awww.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-1532.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESieh-KUtBz8arrJGH7eYme88wa1ytJLAvaqtRdM0iNbfYoHg5PZ5L8C3y8HQGoTeAdulOvxnayGKxp6s92a_ijKdQi7aoRttRfB_wlt7-jIITMu_gDoBO5PhLR2BoV3daIuvwOZ&sig=AHIEtbSd3iWDdPTylCEeHC33srCEq1w5HA) show be helpful.

The Rabin reference at the bottom of the text is from 1978, and the impression I get from p3 of this document is that he came up with a linear iterated hash function in that 1978 paper. So maybe Rabin invented it.

I think we can be pretty sure it was either Merkle, Rabin or Yuval (if you must choose one), but that sounds like an answer correct for a good deal of history questions in this field.

[Alt link](http://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-1532.pdf)

Comment: I can't find the Rabin 78 paper online. The Rabin 79 MIT/LCS/TR-212 does not have iterated hash functions. It's true that hash functions were well known in 1978 as were one-way functions, but I haven't found one-way hash functions before Merkle's thesis.

Comment: It's [this](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0msEAQAAIAAJ&q=0122103505&dq=0122103505&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8ZfRUOWQJKur0AXeq4GABQ&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA) but I can't find the text.

Comment: Yes, the document "The First 30 Years of Cryptographic Hash
Functions and the NIST SHA-3 Competition" has a reference to Rabin 78, and the NIST document makes it clear that Rabin build a hash using DES.  So the answer seems to be "No, it was invented the year before by Rabin."